# Can't Run Logstash in Background from Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, logstash

For some reason, I can't run logstash as a service.  (I had an issue ticket 5 days old, without being touched on elastic/logstash git and forum post across 3 different sites to try and fix it, without luck).  I'm okay with that, and now just want it to run from a bash script.
From command line:

```
cd /opt/logstash
bin/logstash -f [conf_file] > output.txt &
```

everything works as it should, running in the background and outputting to output.txt.  But, when I try to do this via bash with:

```
cd /opt/logstash
bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash_es.conf > var/log/logstash/logstashconsole.txt &
```

logstash starts up in the background, but not listening on the ports it needs to be.  And, if I try to restart, the old logstash instance doesn't release the ports to which it was bound.

Help?

Comment: If Logstash can't open a port for listening it should tell you more about it in the log.

Comment: The console output from --debug?

Comment: You shouldn't need to add `--debug` to see such error messages, but yeah.

Comment: Without debug I have no errors msgs to speak of in /var/log/logstash.   

Can you see the post here, it has my console output: https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/4075  (comment at bottom / latest comment)

If not, I'll repost.  I'm just at character limit

Comment: That log indicates that the UDP and TCP listeners were started successfully. How did you reach the conclusion that that isn't actually the case?

Comment: That's when I start things manually via bin/logstash -f config file --debug.  When I start things as a service, I don't get any console output, err output, etc other than "send logs to /var/log/logstash" or similar.  

When I start things _for the first time_ as a service, I get the same lack of error msgs / feedback, but lsof -i:5514 tells me that logstash is listening. But, logstash doesn't do anything, as described above.  If I try to diagnose things by restarting the service or similar, it doesn't bind back to the ports on the first run, and errors out telling me that they are in use.

Comment: What files do you have in /etc/logstash/conf.d? Any old backup files or similar? Logstash will read _all_ files, so if you have a port listener defined in both foo.conf and foo.conf~ Logstash is going to block itself from listening.

Comment: Just the single config I've mentioned, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is too old to answer. But, my answer will help new users to ELK Stack.

You are doing it correct.

```
cd /opt/logstash
bin/logstash -f [conf_file] > output.txt &
```

All you have to do is `disown` your process.
One way is to remove the job from the shell’s job control using the disown shell builtin:

```
disown
```

If you have more than one background jobs, include % and the job ID after the command:

```
disown %1
```

Confirm that the job is removed from the table of active jobs using the `jobs -l` command. To list all running processes, including the disowned use the `ps aux` command.